# Powershell (7.2.7) Foreach-Object -Parallel - Multi-threading issue

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to collect Azure SQL Server/Database (PaaS) information from thousands of subscriptions. Here's my script.

```
$SQLserver = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag[psobject]]::new()
$subscriptions | Where-Object {$_.state -ne "Disabled" -and $_.State -ne "Warned"} | Foreach-Object -Parallel {
    $sub = $_
    $localSqlserver = $using:SQLserver
    $localSqlserver.Add($(
        Get-AzSqlServer -DefaultProfile (Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $PSItem) | ForEach-Object -process {
        $sqlServerObj = $_
        $sqlServerObj | ForEach-Object -process {
            Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $sqlServerObj.ResourceGroupName -ServerName $sqlServerObj.ServerName | ForEach-Object -process {
            $DBObj = $_
            $DBObj | Select-Object @{N='SubscriptionName'; E = {$sub.Name}},
            @{N='ResourceGroupName';E={$sqlServerObj.ResourceGroupName}},
            @{N='SQLServerName';E={$sqlServerObj.ServerName}},
            @{N='FQDN';E={$sqlServerObj.FullyQualifiedDomainName}},
            @{N='sqlServerResourceId'; E = {$sqlServerObj.ResourceId}},
            @{N='Location';E={$sqlServerObj.Location}},
            @{N='SqlAdministratorLogin';E={$sqlServerObj.SqlAdministratorLogin}},
            @{N='ServerVersion';E={$sqlServerObj.ServerVersion}},
            @{N='Identity';E={$sqlServerObj.Identity}},
            @{N='MinimalTlsVersion';E={$sqlServerObj.MinimalTlsVersion}},
            @{N='PublicNetworkAccess';E={$sqlServerObj.PublicNetworkAccess}},
            @{N='RestrictOutboundNetworkAccess';E={$sqlServerObj.RestrictOutboundNetworkAccess}},
            @{N='KeyId';E={$sqlServerObj.KeyId}},
            @{N='DBName';E={$DBObj.DatabaseName}},
            @{N='DBId';E={$DBObj.DatabaseId}},
            @{N='Edition';E={$DBObj.Edition}},
            @{N='CollationName';E={$DBObj.CollationName}},
            @{N='MaxSizeBytes';E={$DBObj.MaxSizeBytes}},
            @{N='Status';E={$DBObj.Status}},
            @{N='CurrentSize';E={$DBObj.CurrentServiceObjectiveName}},
            @{N='ElasticPoolName';E={$DBObj.ElasticPoolName}},
            @{N='ReadScale';E={$DBObj.ReadScale}},
            @{N='ZoneRedundant';E={$DBObj.ZoneRedundant}},
            @{N='Capacity';E={$DBObj.Capacity}},
            @{N='Family';E={$DBObj.Family}},
            @{N='SkuName';E={$DBObj.SkuName}},
            @{N='LicenseType';E={$DBObj.LicenseType}},
            @{N='CurrentBackupStorageRedundancy';E={$DBObj.CurrentBackupStorageRedundancy}},
            @{N='MaintenanceConfigurationId';E={$DBObj.MaintenanceConfigurationId}},
            @{N='EnableLedger';E={$DBObj.EnableLedger}}
            }}
        }
    ))
} -UseNewRunspace
```

Although `$SQLserver` has collection of objects, I still get the following error message but I  really don't understand what the real problem is and due to this error, it still doesn't contain all the information. But running the script (from line 6) against a single subscription does work.

```
Get-AzSqlDatabase:
Line |
   8 |              Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $sqlServerObj.Resour …
     |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Resource group '911f5f6be3ab-rg' could not be found.
```

```
PSMessageDetails      :
Exception             : Microsoft.Rest.Azure.CloudException: Resource group '911f5f6be3ab-rg' could not be found.
                           at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.DatabasesOperations.ListByServerWithHttpMessagesAsync(String resourceGroupName, String serverName, String skipToken, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
                           at Microsoft.Azure.Management.Sql.DatabasesOperationsExtensions.ListByServerAsync(IDatabasesOperations operations, String resourceGroupName, String serverName, String skipToken, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
                           at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Database.Services.AzureSqlDatabaseCommunicator.List(String resourceGroupName, String serverName)
                           at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Database.Services.AzureSqlDatabaseAdapter.ListDatabases(String resourceGroupName, String serverName)
                           at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Database.Cmdlet.GetAzureSqlDatabase.GetEntity()
                           at Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Common.AzureSqlCmdletBase`2.ExecuteCmdlet()
                           at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Utilities.Common.AzurePSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
TargetObject          :
CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzSqlDatabase], CloudException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.Database.Cmdlet.GetAzureSqlDatabase
ErrorDetails          :
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 8
                        at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 7
                        at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 5
PipelineIterationInfo : {0, 1, 0}
```

Does anyone see any problem with the logic of the script?

Comment: As an aside: To select existing properties from the input objects by their _original name and value_, you don't need a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Calculated_Properties), just use the property _name_; e.g., `ReadScale` instead of `@{N = 'ReadScale'; E = { $_.ReadScale } }`. And if only _renaming_ a property - without transforming its _value_ - is desired, you can use the original property name as a _string_ in the `E` (`Expression`) entry; e.g.: `@{ Name = 'ReadScaleWithNewName'; Expression = 'ReadScale' }`

Answer (score 0):

The error **"Resource group not found"** clearly shows that the database/server does not exist in the specified resource group or that the given resource group is incorrect.

The other issue is with the script is that it uses the `using scope modifier` inside the parallel loop to access the `$SQLserver` collection. This may cause synchronization issues between the parallel threads. The `$SQLserver` collection should be passed as a parameter to the `ForEach -Object` cmdlet.

***I modified your script as shown below and it worked for me as expected.***

*I tried retrieving only a few fields to verify that it was working properly. You can change it to meet your requirements.*

```sql
$SQLserver = [System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag[psobject]]::new()
ForEach-Object  {
    $sub = $_
    $sqlServers = Get-AzSqlServer -DefaultProfile (Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscription)
    $sqlServers | ForEach-Object {
        $sqlServerObj = $_
        $databases = Get-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $sqlServerObj.ResourceGroupName -ServerName $sqlServerObj.ServerName
        $databases | ForEach-Object {
            $DBObj = $_
            $SQLserver.Add([pscustomobject]@{
                SubscriptionName = $sub.Name
                ResourceGroupName = $sqlServerObj.ResourceGroupName
                SQLServerName = $sqlServerObj.ServerName
                sqlServerResourceId = $sqlServerObj.ResourceId
                Location = $sqlServerObj.Location
                SqlAdministratorLogin = $sqlServerObj.SqlAdministratorLogin
                ServerVersion = $sqlServerObj.ServerVersion
                Identity = $sqlServerObj.Identity
                MinimalTlsVersion = $sqlServerObj.MinimalTlsVersion
                PublicNetworkAccess = $sqlServerObj.PublicNetworkAccess
              })
        }
    }
}
```

***Output:***

[image]